# How to select on reactive variable Shiny R

Tags: shiny, reactive-programming

I have data frame with 2 columns (ID, Name) and selectinput to select name (readable for human). On name selected I want to select ID and use this ID in loop (myVar).

```
library(shiny)

ID <- c(1,2,3)  
Name <- c("a","b","c")
myDF <- data.frame(ID, Name)

ui <- fluidPage(
  selectInput("wyb", "Wybierz", myDF$Name)
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  myVar <- subset(myDF, Name == input$wyb, ID)  
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 0):

As you are using `input$wyb`, you will need an observer on the server side as shown below.

```
library(shiny)

ID <- c(2,3,4)  
Name <- c("a","b","c")
myDF <- data.frame(ID, Name)

ui <- fluidPage(
  selectInput("wyb", "Wybierz", myDF$Name),
  DTOutput("tb1")
  
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  observe({
    req(input$wyb)
    myVar <- subset(myDF, Name == input$wyb)
  
  mydf <- subset(mtcars, mtcars$cyl==myVar$ID*2)
  
  output$tb1 <- renderDT(mydf)
  })
   
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: How can I use myVar in loop? Could You send an example? @YBS

Comment: Please try the attached code.  I am not sure what you are trying to achieve.  So, please try to explain what you are trying to do and what you have tried so far.

Comment: Step 1 - I want user to chose project (user see Project name and I need project ID - in this example ID and name are stored in myDF. Step 2 - I want to send request to API (to do this I need project ID not project name for project selected by user). @YBS

Comment: You should be able to pick-up the project ID with myVar$ID.  You can match the project ID as  `projectID %in% myVar$ID`

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @YBS for solution.

```
    library(shiny)
ID <- c(2,3,4)  
Name <- c("a","b","c")
myDF <- data.frame(ID, Name)

ui <- fluidPage(
  selectInput("wyb", "Wybierz", myDF$Name),
  textOutput("txt1")
  
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  observe({
    req(input$wyb)
    myVar <- subset(myDF, Name == input$wyb)
    for(i in 1:myVar$ID) {print(i)} 
  })
  
  
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```